# How to filter a RDD according to list of values

Tags: scala, rdd

I am able to accomplish a filter for RDD[Test] using a specific value

```
Test.filter(_.state == "NY")
```

I need to extend this to be able to filter Test with multiple values like ("NY","CA","PA")

Is there an "in list" or in ("NY","CA","PA") in scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put values in Set and filter the following way:

```
val set = Set("NY", "CA", "PA")
rdd.filter(item => set(item.state))
```

to test if value is in set:

```
set.contains(value)
```

or

```
set(value)
```

Comment: is there an INVERSE test..or can that be achieve with !set.contains(value)